# axis alignment for 3D graph using matlab2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

I am trying to include multiple 3D figures (created in matlab) into a latex file.

The original 3D figures in matlab look like this:

[image]

In the .m file that creates these figures, I use

```
ylabel('transformed W_t/D_t','VerticalAlignment','bottom')   
xlabel('\lambda_t','VerticalAlignment','bottom')
```

to move the xlabel and ylabel up.

Then I use

```
 matlab2tikz('figure2a_2.tikz', 'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth','extraAxisOptions','zticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}')
```

to convert the file to a .tikz file.

In Latex, I run

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering 
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{5cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm}  
\input{Figure2a_2.tikz}
 \caption{{\bf Structure of model: capital can be invested in a bank sector and an equity sector.} An intermediary has the expertise to reallocate capital between the sectors and to monitor bank capital against bank crashes.}
\label{fig1} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and obtain the following figures:
[image]

The problem is that now the xlabel and ylabel are too far away from the 3d plots, and I want to move them UP a bit. Is this feasible? Is there some option value to pass into the `matlab2tikz` command? Or maybe write some global specification for `pgfplots` in the .tex file?

I've been trying to fix this for hours but nothing works. Many thanks for your help!

Note: I cannot do the plots directly in latex using `tikzpicture` since the original data files need many manipulations and I prefer doing them in matlab.

Comment: What has to do the `biblatex` tag with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured this out, by simply using:

```
 matlab2tikz('figure2a_2.tikz', 'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth','extraAxisOptions','zticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},ylabel style={yshift=0.9em}');
```

for the conversion and have

```
\pgfplotsset{scaled z ticks=false}
```

in the .tex file setup.
Thanks.